# self.navigationController is nil during state restoration

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload

After implementing state restoration in my app I am having difficulty with my view controllers.

My issue is that in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller I am attempting to restore the `self.naigationController` property, which is `nil`.

I have set breakpoints in the `viewDidLoad` method of each view controller that comes before the one I am trying to restore. In the first view controller, the navigation controller is found. In every one after that, including the one I am trying to restore, the navigation controller is `nil`.

This is causing bugs where I cannot set the navigation bar visibility, views are misplaced, etc.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Comment: Is the navigation controller only missing during `viewDidLoad`? Or is still missing when state restoration completes?

Comment: Good question. It is there once I do anything with my view controller. Why do you think this is?

Comment: I haven't used state restoration a ton, but it's possible it restores view controllers in the opposite order that they were encoded. Can you move the code to `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Actually, yes. That does help. I still have some bugs that seem to be resulting from this, but I'm getting closer. This seems like strange behaviour and I would like to know more about state restoration to understand this better. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the code to `viewWillAppear`.

Unlike `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` can get called multiple times, so take care to make sure your code is idempotent. That is, make sure the results are what you expect if the method is called repeatedly. For example, make sure you don't initialize a new subview if the view has already been added.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I am still wondering exactly when the navigation controller exists and why.

Answer (score 0):

The `navigationController` property searches up the `parentViewController`s to find one of class `UINavigationController`. Only view controllers loaded from the storyboard can find their navigation controller at the `viewDidLoad` time (and in `awakeFromNib`). It is likely you are instantiating a new instance of the view controller during the restore process rather than using the one that was created by the storyboard. The solution is either to help the restore process find the existing view controller if it has changed paths e.g. because of split controller orientation change (via `viewControllerForRestorationPathComponents` in your app delegate) although that comes with its own set of issues, or make your view controller work by not requiring the nav controller in the `viewDidLoad`, e.g. put it in the `viewWillAppear` as others have suggested.